# Mono 3.2.3 requires a newer version of glibc

Tags: linux, mono, glibc, yum

I am using Red Hat and trying to install the latest Mono version from http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.2.3/linux/x64/.

I used the following command to try installing mono core:

```
 sudo yum install http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.2.3/linux/x64/mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64.rpm
```

The following are my error messages:

```
Error: Package: mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64 (/mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64 (/mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit)
Error: Package: mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64 (/mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mono-core-3.2.3-135.2.x86_64 (Mono_Factory)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit)
```

I have glibc 2.12 in my OS. But Mono requires 2.16. If i try to update glibc, I might run into kernel issues. What are my options in this case? Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> I might run into kernel issues.

What makes you believe that?

Generally, newer GLIBC versions will continue to run fine on older kernels (up to a limit).

> What are my options in this case?

The obvious option is to update glibc. The other alternative is to install a separate newer version in non-default location. Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Answer (score 0):

Updating GLIBC with Red Hat Enterprise Linux is a very non-trivial task.  In every case with my 8 years of linux experience, I have always given up on this approach, and either installed the latest Fedora Core, or found some good soul who has ported code to support the older GLIBC version.

Usually EPEL is a great place for maintaining these compatability issues, however for the case of mono they don't have the latest 3.x build (as of 2014).

Long story short, the developers at Mono have screwed the pooch to say the least for supporting RHEL 6.